# Ionic Pro- iOS Build Code signing

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this problem, when build the code in Ionic pro xcode 9 fails and show the next message:

> ▸ Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the "..." target's entitlements file. Remove the entitlements or switch to manual signing and resolve the issue by downloading a provisioning profile from the developer website.
>   ▸ Provisioning profile "..." doesn't include the aps-environment entitlement.
>   ▸ Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'

The code has the correct certificate also i changed xcode9 to xcode8, reinstalled plugins and check one per one but the error continues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS have new version of sdk so generate one new Provisioning Profile and update the app in IONIC.

Answer (score 0):

Apple now requires an explicit app id instead of a wildcard. You'll need to generate a new provisioning profile directly in your apple developer account using the full bundle id. Here's what I see in your the build logs for an xcode9 build.